# Issue in lookup field when items are too large in lookup list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, list, jquery, jslink

I have issue in lookup field. When item in lookup field are too large, it throws error "***Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.***".

Is there any solution for that without hiding that column?

I want that field in my new item form but new item form is not opening due to large number of items in lookup field.

I do not want all the lookup items in that field. I just want empty dropdown of that lookup field so i can set value using jslink and lookup field data is saved when i click on Save button.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display this field on new item form? Or just to set value by JS, not user?

Comment: I want empty dropdown in new form. I have all lookup field in separate popup with pagination. so user will select value from popup that will be added to lookup dropdown so when user save it, lookup field value also be saved @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used for the similar task:

1. Get Lookup Id from query string

`<ParameterBinding Name="RootDocId" Location="QueryString(RootDocID)" DefaultValue=""/>`

2. Replace on NewForm.aspx

`<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff5{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="RootDocument" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@RootDocument')}"/>`

with

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="ff5{$Pos}" text="{$RootDocId}" value="{$RootDocId}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Text','TextChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@RootDocument')}" />`

[Building custom forms](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx)

UPD:
To use custom form:

1. Open NewForm.aspx in Designer
2. Place cursor just above `<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart>` tag - the default form
3. From "Insert" tab on ribbon use "New Form" button to place it on page
4. Drop the default form from page.

Comment: where should i put this code @Alex?

Comment: on the new item form (generated by Designer).
If you use multiple lookup field, then text value should be "1;#;#2;#;#3;#;#4". You can hide text input and use it in backstage @RajeshJoshi

Comment: My question is when i open new form, there are appox 150k data in lookup field so page is not event loading throw "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property." error before loading page.

Comment: Create New Form by Designer. It will generate code with separate fields. Then you can replace lookup column field to text input with binding

Comment: I opened the new form in designer but i cant any find text <SharePoint:FormField

Comment: @RajeshJoshi, I'd edited the answer with guide to create your custom new form.

Comment: Add your own dropdown list with this `TextBox` (`display:none` to hide), but fill it with IDs from your own JS/Popup.

Comment: I created a custom form using your way. Removed the lookup Field from my form and added my own control. Add my customized save button and it is working now. Thanks @AlexZh

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing `maxJsonLength` in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="10000000"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried that but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Why can't the JSon set for the drop down field be emptied or nullified and then assigned, so that the control is empty as expected on loading.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePointDesigner  we created 3 forms realted with the list (New, Edit,Display).
These forms are the default ones.

Now we can open, edit and create items.